# SQL Browser service doesn't work when Login account is anything but LocalSystem

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a named instance of SQL Server 2008 R2. When I attempt to connect to the named instance I get the following error (if the browser service is set to logon as anything other than Local System):

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

When I change the account I use SQL Server Configuration Manager and have tried Local Service, Network Service, and a local account. I made sure the local account was a member of the "SQLServer2005SQLBrowserUser$MachineName" local group and has all the rights specified [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181087%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

How can I use a local account as the log on account for the SQL Browser service?

Answer (score 2):

SQL Browser reads instance network configuration information from the registry; maybe the permissions there got messed up.  Verify that the account you're using has access to read info underneath the following key:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQLServer\
```

Comment: For whatever reason, your method didn't work, but granting read on the parent (HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\ in your example) did work. Also, this key will be different for a named instance - replace MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER with MSSQL10_50.INSTANCENAME)

Answer (score 0):

The account running the SQL Browser service must have read permissions on the following key: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\ (for a named instance, replace MSSQLSERVER with instance name). Thanks to squillman for putting me on the right track.